# Flink: getRecord() not getting called in AggregateFunction

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to create a TumblingWindow on a stream of continuous data and create aggregates within the window. But for some reason, the getResult() does not get called.

```
public class MyAggregator implements AggregateFunction<Event, MyMetrics, MyMetrics> {

    @Override
    public MyMetrics createAccumulator() {
        return new MyMetrics(0L, 0L);
    }


    @Override
    public MyMetrics add(Event value, MyMetrics accumulator) {
        Instant previousValue = ...;
        if (previousValue != null) {
            Long myWay = ...;
            accumulator.setMyWay(myWay);
        }
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public MyMetrics getResult(MyMetrics accumulator) {
        System.out.println("Inside getResult()");
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public MyMetrics merge(MyMetrics acc1, MyMetrics acc2) {
        return new MyMetrics(
                acc1.getMyWay() + acc2.getMyWay());
    }
}
```

Note: event.getClientTime() returns an Instant object.

```
private WatermarkStrategy getWatermarkStrategy() {
        return WatermarkStrategy
                .<MyEvent>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                .withTimestampAssigner(
                        (event, timestamp) ->
                                event.getClientTime().toEpochMilli()
                );
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataStream<MyEvent> watermarkedData = actuals
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                        getWatermarkStrategy()
                ).name("addWatermark");

        final OutputTag<MyEvent> lateOutputTag = new OutputTag<MyEvent>("late-data"){};

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<OutputModel> output_data = watermarkedData
                .keyBy("input_key")
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(1)))
                .sideOutputLateData(lateOutputTag)
                .aggregate(
                        new MyAggregator(),
                ).name("AggregationRollUp");

        output_data.addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>());

}
```

Any pointers as to what I am missing here would be helpful.

Comment: This would seem to indicate that the window is never being triggered. This will occur if you don't have enough input data to advance the watermark far enough.

Answer (score 0):

First check the timing of the data to see if it meets the window trigger conditions

Second may be you can do a test by reducing the window size from 1h to 1min and reducing the watermark region from 10min to 30s